# Confusion over IIS versions

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

I have built a new server with a clean install of **Windows Server 2016** and noticed a few strange things about IIS.

1. **IIS 10.0** is located inside the `System32` folder.

   - Does this mean it is a 32bit exe, and therefore incapable of running 64bit web code?
   - Is there both a 32bit and 64bit version of IIS?
   - If so, how can I tell which I have?
   - If not then why are there two versions of some extensions? eg https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite#additionalDownloads
2. **IIS 6** is also located in the same folder (*InetMgr6.exe*).   In gods name, why !!?
3. If I run IIS 6 it tells me that I have **IIS 7.5** running on this server!
4. If I dig deeper, IIS 6 says it is running an *SMTP Server*.
   What's thats all about?

Help me make sense of all this !

Comment: Did you installed the Legacy management tool feature, as pretty sure it can’t detect version 10 of IIS, check in the IIS role, you will see it there you selected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%windir%\System32` is a 64 bit system folder on Windows 64 bit (32 bit on Windows 32 bit), while `%windir%\WOW64` is the 32 bit system folder on Windows 64 bit. Memorize that if you haven't yet.

On Windows 32 bit, IIS is purely 32 bit.

On Windows 64 bit, IIS contains both 64 bit and 32 bit components, so that it can run both 64 bit and 32 bit web apps.

Microsoft ships 32 bit and 64 bit MSI packages, which is for 32 bit and 64 bit Windows releases.

`InetMgr6.exe` is the legacy tool for only SMTP service. It has nothing to do with IIS any more so you can neglect it. It was there for compatibility purposes. If you do want to learn, Google "IIS SMTP". As it is a legacy tool, if it tells you something like IIS 7.5, don't believe in it either.

Lastly, you are using Windows Server 2016, so you are using IIS 10, not IIS 7.5. Each IIS releases bind to a Windows release, and IIS 7.5 is only on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Thanks! The System32 folder is confusing, why don't they just stick to System!

Comment: So is it not possible to host SMTP service on IIS10?

Comment: They cannot. The backward compatibility of Windows is well maintained by keeping such crazy names. You can still use the legacy SMTP service if you want, but it is not part of IIS 10, as Microsoft hasn't updated it since IIS 6 (that's why it still requires `InetMgr6.exe`. You should switch to Exchange or third party SMTP service if you want new features.